# not able to update my package on pypi.org

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi, twine

I have made changes [to package I had submitted](https://pypi.org/project/maildiff/#description) long time back in 2015 now today I added support markdown on pypi and updated setup.py to support pip version 10,

however now I am facing a strange problem: If I run this command

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r http://pypi.org


Password:  # I enter the password
Submitting dist/maildiff-1.2.1.tar.gz to http://pypi.org
Server response (200): OK
```

but on pypi its not updated.
The strange part is even if I enter wrong password I get the message

```
Submitting dist/maildiff-1.2.1.tar.gz to http://pypi.org
Server response (200): OK
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you use `twine` to handle your PyPI management needs, and that you use `test.pypi.org` first to test your process. See https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#uploading-the-distribution-archives

Comment: Also did you use `setup.py register` *first*?

Comment: well of course , how did I got my package up here https://pypi.org/project/maildiff/#history at first place, I am able to login to pypi

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am able to submit using twine to testPyPi, https://test.pypi.org/project/maildiff/#history but if try `twine upload --repository-url https://pypi.org/ dist/*` I get this: Uploading maildiff-1.2.1.tar.gz
100%|██████████████████████████████████████| 16.3k/16.3k [00:01<00:00, 11.5kB/s]
`HTTPError: 405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url: https://pypi.org/`

Comment: the url for test.pypi has a path you forgot to include. Better still, just use the default repository url (don’t use the switch)

Comment: used without switch, progress but now I am getting this: ubmitting dist/maildiff-1.2.1.tar.gz to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Upload failed (403): Invalid or non-existent authentication information.
error: Upload failed (403): Invalid or non-existent authentication information. I have tried entering password 10-15 times with new updated password but no success

Comment: And your login does work directly on the pypi.org website, in your browser? Use https://pypi.org/account/login/ to see if you still have access there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Martjin Pieters knew I will get my answer myself, I think I have spoken to him quite a lot of time on SO, so as I was troubleshooting I finally managed to upload to pypi:

I am not sure which one approach worked

```
twine upload --repository-url https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

or

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

but its finally up yay...
Thanks for your inputs @Martjin and your valued time (y)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following commands after installing the module twine with Python 3

```
twine upload  dist/*
username: Enter your https://pypi.org username
Password: Enter your https://pypi.org password
```

Note: before uploading the package, you must verify your email ID from your pypi account.